# category doesn't showing up in admin

Tags: categories, admin

After WordPress update certain of my categories doesn't showing up in admin,but it's ok in the DB, and it display in the parent dropdown,
[image]
how i can fix this please

Comment: Is that list paged? It says 9 elements but only shows 3. Have you disabled all plugins?

Comment: no paged, the other 6 elements are only show in the parent dropdown, all plugins are disabled

Comment: Switch themes to Twenty Thirteen. Something is very odd.

Comment: i tried, nothing happened

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: nothing, i can delete them for test, and re-add them, but all posts will lose their categories

Comment: Sorry. I cannot duplicate this. Without more information, I don't know what to say.